# Make a div auto expand width to the left instead of the right

Tags: css, html

I have a div on my website which contains a list of items which acts as a menu. I have set the CSS `width:auto` so that it will re-size if a menu item is too long. At the moment though, this will expand to the right and "pushes" the rest of my content to the right as well.

This is hard to explain so as an example if you go to http://redsquirrelsoftware.co.uk/ and click on the Support menu item, you can see the content being pushed across. What I want to happen is for the div to expand into the white space to the left of the menu.

The CSS I have for the div at the moment is:

```
.sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 25%;
    max-width: 29%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Is there any way for it to expand the other way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about changing margin-left: 40px to 20px and setting the width for the child <ul> tag? So it will wrap the words, when they are too long and leave more space for them.

Comment: @user4035 Changing the `margin-left` to 20px does stop it from expanding the div to the right, but that's only because the text isn't long enough any more - people using a netbook for example will still have the same issue. I did try wrapping words onto a new line to begin with but it looked untidy, so was hoping for a solution which would just expand to the left instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This idea needs testing, but it works in Chrome at least:

- Change `.content` and `.sidebar1` to `float: right` instead of `float: left`.
- In the HTML, move `.sidebar1` after `.content`.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, and it did make it expand to the left instead of the right, but it put the menu to the right of the content. I tried changing `.content` to `float: left` and `float: right` but neither worked (using Chrome).

Answer (score 15):

Another way I found to do this without using floats or absolute positioning is to use `direction: rtl` on the parent, and then reset it on the children:

```
.parent { direction: rtl; }
.parent > * { direction: ltr; }
.child { width: 200px; }
.child:hover { width: 400px; }
```

Code pen: http://codepen.io/heisters/pen/gMgboJ

(sorry, I couldn't base the example on the OP's site, since the link appears to be dead).

Comment: This answer is now supported by almost all major browsers (as June 2019).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
.sidebar1{
   right:0;left:inherit;
}
```

this should be applied to the div(menu) which are on the right side of your screen