# Expand div width to left direction to fit its content

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a structure of div:

```css
img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span>Hello user</span>
  <span>
    <img src="https://en.opensuse.org/images/0/0b/Icon-user.png">
  </span>
  <span>Register</span> | 
  <span>Login</span>
</div>
```

What I want is: When the length of **user** is longer, **div container** must expand its width to the left direction (right direction is fixed) to fit its content.
**Note:** This is not animation or transition, **user** is an account.

Comment: you will need help of javascript for that

Comment: Could you make an example for me?

Comment: instead of expanding you can display only some part of the name and display full name on hover .. because if you expand in left direction .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
margin: auto;
float: right;
```

Answer (score -2):

Set width auto to the div, it will rearrange itself to fits inside the container.

There are multiple ways to get that to expand to the left.  You can use floats or absolute positioning.  Another way is to set *direction* to *rtl* for a parent node and then to *ltr* on the child.

Comment: I tried, but it expands its width to the right direction.

Comment: Have a look at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600743/make-a-div-auto-expand-width-to-the-left-instead-of-the-right

Comment: Use direction: rtl for parent and direction: ltr for child will work.